# Is it bad to format a used SSD so it can be used again for cloning?

Tags: ssd, formatting, clone

I have a Samsung 850 Pro SSD that I used at my previous job. I would like to reuse this SSD and clone the HDD on my current work laptop. I dont need any of the old files on the SSD. Can I just format the whole drive and then clone to it? I recall reading in the past that formatting an SSD is bad for the drive.

Comment: There are no issues with formatting SSDs

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what your formatting program does. Nowadays, most formatting software will issue a [TRIM command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(computing)) on the entire partition before starting the format operation, which will cleanly tell the SSD to get rid of all data in that partition, thus maximizing performance and reducing wear.

If you want to make absolutely sure that this happens in the cleanest way possible and that the entire SSD gets reset, you should issue a [Secure Erase command](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase) before formatting. Arguably this is even cleaner than trying to issue a TRIM command across the entire drive, and you will get actual feedback about whether the operation was successful or not.

And of course, just like user576053 suggested in the other answer, do make sure to use a quick format (that's usually the default option), not a "full format", which is pointless and can even be slightly harmful with SSDs.

Comment: Thanks Etienne. I apologize for the late reply. Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you format it, if you use quick format than that just writes a few blocks so it's absolutely not bad for the drive. If you try some sort of full format and the program you're using to format it doesn't recognize it's an SSD, it could try rewriting all blocks, which is a problem for SSDs the same way wiping free space does not work like on traditional HDs.

Answer (score -1):

Solid-state drives can only support a limited number of read/write cycles, so you want to minimize the amount of unnecessary read/write operations that it performs. (This is not meant to imply that HDDs can last forever, they most certainly cannot.) <s>To get the most out of your SSD, you should avoid formatting the drive unnecessarily, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't do it at all. If you would like to format an SSD, you should probably use a "quick format" option instead of a "full format" option.</s>

Similarly, SSDs experience next to no improvement in performance from defragmenting. You should never defragment your SSD, as this will only wear it out prematurely!

You can check out these links for a little bit more information, if you like:

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/281081-32-formatting-secure-erase-quick-format

https://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/storage/how-format-ssd-3588491/

http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/210492-extremetech-explains-how-do-ssds-work

Edit:

Musselman LLC cleared this up for me. Apparently, the number of read/write cycles is far more than the average consumer could possible use in reasonable conditions. You really don't need to worry about wearing out your SSD by formatting it.

<s>My comment about defragmenting, however, still stands. There's no need to defragment an SSD; it's just a waste of time and energy.</s>

https://techreport.com/review/27909/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-theyre-all-dead

Edit 2:

I'm wrong. Here's another article that may help you. It helped me to see the bigger picture (thanks Etienne):

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheRealAndCompleteStoryDoesWindowsDefragmentYourSSD.aspx

In short: don't bloody worry about it.

Comment: Do you know what that limited number of write cycles is?  It is something like 100,000 writes.  "flash wear appeared after 200TB" && "Even 100TB is far more endurance than the typical consumer needs."  http://techreport.com/review/27909/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-theyre-all-dead  He basically dban'ed them for 18 months straight to break them.  Most of what you are saying is true, but you are scaring them when the possibility of them wearing out an SSD is nearly impossible.

Comment: No, I wasn't aware of what the actual numbers were. I wasn't trying to scare anyone; I was just trying to provide information based on what I knew, which clearly wasn't the full picture. Thanks for the input, Musselman!

Comment: "There's no need to defragment an SSD; it's just a waste of time and energy." > [That's not true.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheRealAndCompleteStoryDoesWindowsDefragmentYourSSD.aspx)

Comment: Guess I was wrong on all counts. I edited my answer.